# JavaScript: skipping to the next array in 3d array when if statement fulfilled

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on a problem that requires me to get a certain number with a given 3d array. That Array Contains 2D arrays which contain a number x amount of time. Parent array sorted from bigger to smaller.

Example of parent array;

```
array = [
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [4, 4, 4],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];
```

and number I want to get is 27;

```
let number = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
 number += array[i][j]
 }
}
```

The for loop above is obviously sums every number in the parent array but I want it to skip the loop when the number passes the 27 and finally break when it is 27.

For the example above, in the first loop, it should run until the number is 25 and skip to the second loop;
the second and third loops skip because the number needs to be equal to 27;
and finally, the loop breaks in the second run of the fourth loop when the number is 27;

I'm sorry for this long-ass and bloated explanation, my js knowledge is limited I have to try to explain it in words.

Comment: There is no `3-D` array, `array` is `2-D`.

Comment: What result you want in return?

Comment: I can see you are increasing `number` with `number += array[i][j]` but where is your logic code / value checking code to see if `number >= 27`? Please include what you have tried in the question.

Comment: @navnath I edited the question to make it more clear. I want to loop through the array until the number is 27 and I will use those i and j values for something else.

Comment: So you're trying to stop looping when you get to a given target number, but for what purpose? Is this just a test to see if you can get to 27 before you run through the array?

Comment: @Tigger This is totally for example purposes, I simplified the problem to make it even questionable. I will use values of i and j not the given number

Comment: @kmoser This is totally for example purposes, I simplified the problem to make it even questionable. I will use values of i and j not the given number

Comment: @HR01M8055 so "3d" should be 2d and "2d" should be 1d or just an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var target = 27; // Or whatever

let number = 0;
let helpers = []

for (let i = 0; number < target && i < array.length; i++){
    helper = []
    for (let j = 0; number < target && j < array[i].length; j++){
        if ( number + array[i][j] <= target ) {
            helper.push(array[i][j])
            if ( ( number += array[i][j] ) == target ) {
                helpers.push(helper)
                helper = []
                console.log( `Found target ${target} at i=${i}, j=${j}` );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (helper.length) {
        helpers.push(helper)
    }
}

console.log(helpers)
```

Comment: How can I get data of arrays and their elements used in making the 27; Like, if I create a helper array for storing that and pushing every element that went into making number. But in the parent array's structure; e.g. helperArr = [[5,5,5,5,5],[1,1]]

Comment: @RasulAli It would be much easier to help you if you include all your requirements in your original post. In any case, I have updated my answer to include the array of helper arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I have been working on a problem for last night. I even edited question 3-4 times after posting because I made mistakes. Thank you for your patience and help :) This should do the trick;